# Dependency Injection failing in ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.1.11

I have just initialized a database I will be using in my Website.

I used the `Scaffold-DbContext` command successfully, and it has now created all the model classes and data context class.

In the `StartUp.ConfigureServices` I have the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connection = //correct connection string used in Scaffolding
    services.AddDbContext<Models.WebsiteContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

In my view, I have the following simple thing to test to see if it is working correctly:

```
@page
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Levels>

<table>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@item.Id</td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

But unfortunately I get a cryptic error message that I'm not sure what it means:

[image]

To further add: when I debug the project, the constructor of the context does not get hit. I'm not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency injection is a technique for achieving inversion of control it is majorly to inject a service into the constructor of the class where it will be used.

Basically, you inject a service from an interface it implements. for instance

If you have an interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
     void doMyWork();
}
```

And then you had a service that implements this interface

```
public class MyService : IMyInterface
{    
    public void doMyWork() {
        //the work is done here
        //get to the db and fetch some good stuff the users needs
    } 
}
```

An you want to use DI to call this service from your controller if you are using MVC

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyInterface _myinterface;

    public HomeController(IMyInterface myinterface)
    {
        _myinterface = myinterface;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
         var theWork = _myinterface.doMyWork();
    }
}
```

So lets say you are using a db connection as in your case your startup config needs to bind the service and the interface `services.AddSingleton`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connection = //correct connection string used in Scaffolding
    services.AddDbContext<Models.WebsiteContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyService>();

    services.AddMvc()
}
```

for more on DI for ASP.NET Core see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: oh so you have to have a controller?

Comment: in my ConfigureServices, I just have the services.AddMvc()      what exactly does that do  -- vs AddSingleton?

Comment: It is basically the way you tell your application that you want the MVC sevices available. Again you must not necessarily have a controller, injection happens in the constructor of the class/controller.

Comment: How would I access the database / display on view without controller?

Comment: You need the Controller to Route actions to the view. even if you are building with a webapi it has to be a Controller always a Controller provided you are doing MVC. you can access the database without the controller but you cannot display on the view without a controller

Comment: I saw a sample code -- that did not use interfaces / class example you used above. Instead all the code it had was  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);  services.AddMvc();     Not sure how they managed to set up the controller without adding the Singleton/Scoped as you showed above

Comment: If you are not using DI, the you don't need Singleton, you communicate to your db directly from the controller. DI is just a way to inject a service in your controller or any other class without using the `new` keyword. See that there was no new keyword in my example. If you're not using DI, you can use the service directly with `new MyService()` and it gets instantiated. But DI handles that instantiation for you. See application insight telemetry [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Application-Insights-for-ASP.NET-Core)

Comment: See dependency injection explained in plain English [here](https://www.codementor.io/olotintemitope/dependency-injection-explained-in-plain-english-b24hippx7) also see explanation [here](https://stackify.com/dependency-injection/)